# SQL's equivalent to C#'s User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Is there an SQL equivalent to ASP.Net/C#'s "User.Identity.Name" to output a user's windows domain?  I have a formview in an ASP.net web application where a textbox is for Username.  The username is pulled from the user's windows domain.  The User.Identity.Name command puts that value in the textbox when I'm filling out the form, but when I insert the record into the gridview, that represents the SQL dababase table, nothing shows.  So I'm thinking it has to do with changing the "Default Value or Binding" value in the sql table design under "Username" but I'm not sure what the command is.

The other field that is giving trouble in translation is UserDate.  This retrieves the current date and time that a record was inserted.  Again, when I fill out the formview form, it automatically populates the Userdate field with the current date and time, which is what I want, but when I insert, nothing shows in the gridview.  However, if I manually insert data/records  DIRECTLY into the SQL server as a query, which DOESNT include the UserDate column, the gridview shows the date and time , but it doesn't show in the SQL database while everything else does.

HTML Markup:

```
            Username:
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# User.Identity.Name %>' />
            <br />
            UserDate:
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%#  DateTime.Now %>' />
            <br />
```

SQL Query I use to directly populate records into the database:

```
insert into dbo.PO_Table (PO_ID, PO_Title, Date_Received, Date_Completed)
Values(100,'First PO',01/01/01,02/02/02);

insert into dbo.PO_Table (PO_ID, PO_Title, Date_Received, Date_Completed)
Values(200,'Second PO',03/03/03,04/04/04);

insert into dbo.PO_Table (PO_ID, PO_Title, Date_Received, Date_Completed)
Values(300,'Third PO',05/05/05,06/06/06);
```

My Insert Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPO]
    @PO_ID INT,
    @PO_Title nvarchar(50),
    @Date_Received date,
    @Date_Completed date,
    @PO_Note nvarchar(50),
@Username varchar(30),
@UserDate date


AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.PO_Table(PO_ID,PO_Title,Date_Received,Date_Completed,Username,UserDate,PO_Note)
VALUES(@PO_ID,@PO_Title,@Date_Received,@Date_Completed,@Username,@UserDate,@PO_Note);


   insert into task (PO_AutoID,PO_ID)
SELECT PO_AutoID,PO_ID
FROM po_table
WHERE PO_ID = @PO_ID
END
```

Comment: There is the [`SYSTEM_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) keyword.

Comment: Actually I figured out the Date one.  Just do SET @UserDate = GetDate()

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You want either SUSER_SNAME() OR SUSER_NAME()

```
SELECT 
USER_ID() as UserId, USER_NAME() as UserName, 
USER_SID() as UserSId, SUSER_SNAME() as SUserSName, 
SUSER_ID() as SUserId, SUSER_NAME() as SUserName, 
SUSER_SID() as SUserSId
```

SUSER_SNAME() returns DOMAIN\USER

I missed the second part of the question.

GETDATE() will return the current date of the SQL Server

Comment: SUSER_SNAME will return the user with which you are log on in the database, USER_NAME() will return your first User in the sql server, User_Name(3) will return the 4.

Comment: Thank you.  I have the date working, but with the username....  When I use the formview, it shows my username, but when I insert, the gridview shows the IIS APPPOOL name.

Comment: It's using the identity of the app pool to connect to the server. What happens when you add <identity impersonate="true" /> to your web.config?

Comment: Thank you!  It gave me the right value now.  While on this topic and thread, why is GetDate() giving me just the date and not the time?  Isn't it supposed to be both?  I'm getting "1/12/2015 12:00:00 AM" when it's 9:46AM

Comment: what is the column in the table defined as? Getdate() should give you everything up to the millisecond I.e. '2015-01-12 16:47:14.857'

Comment: Nevermind, that was a dumb question on my part.  In my stored procedure I had Userdate date and not Userdate datetime.  That fixed it.